# Anyone successfully used eclipse and adb with a Swees Smart 18

Tags: eclipse, adb

I've just bought a Swees smart 18 phone, mainly to check that code developed for my Nexus 7 will look okay on such a small screen.
However, adb reports insufficient permissions for device when I try to use logcat (logcat *:E *:I), and the eclipse android SDK which I'm using can't recognise the serial number.
FWIW it's model number X416 running version 4.2.2 with kernel version 3.4.5

Anyone successfully developed with one of these?

Answer (score 0):

Answering my own question again, in case it helps someone else.
The problem is that I wasn't running adb as root, so I added
    sudo ./adb start-server
to my adb start script; which I run before starting eclipse ADT.